# How to configure a custom process to capture stdout from container in Kubernetes

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

Using Kubernetes / Amazon EKS, is there a way to configure a custom containerized process that can capture the logging/stdio from your main containerized application?

Background:
Instead of using pre-packaged solutions like fluentd or logstash, we already have an application that can read from stdin and write to where we want to, we just need to hook it up to containers running in Kubernetes, *somehow*.

Answer (score 1):

Everything a containerized application writes to `stdout` and `stderr` is handled and redirected somewhere by a container engine.

The Docker container engine redirects those two streams to a logging driver, configured in Kubernetes, to write to a file under `/var/log/containers` on the host system in json format. These are the same logs `kubectl logs` shows

[image: Logging at the node level]

See [this kubernetes document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) for more information and more complicated logging solutions like using a node logging agent or a sidecar container. Or you could have your application write directly to your logging files/api/backend

This timber.io [blog post](https://timber.io/blog/collecting-application-logs-on-kubernetes/) contains a full walkthrough on finding logs, setting up logging, and shipping logs out using the example manifests on [their github](https://github.com/timberio/examples/tree/master/kubernetes)